# DirectoryNotFoundException - while uploading photos to facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk

I am developing a windows phone app using facebook c# sdk. I am having a problem uploading a photo to a facebook wall. The exception occurred on the line "var imageStream = File.OpenRead(imagepath);". What i did wrong here??

```
void cameraCaptureTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(e.OriginalFileName, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            //Code to display the photo on the page in an image control named myImage.
            WriteableBitmap bmp = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(e.ChosenPhoto);

            myImage.Source = bmp;

            imageSource = this.SaveImageToLocalStorage(bmp,System.IO.Path.GetFileName(e.OriginalFileName));
        }
    }

    private string SaveImageToLocalStorage(WriteableBitmap image, string imageFileName)
    {

        if (image == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("imageBytes");
        }
        try
        {
            var isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

            if (!isoFile.DirectoryExists("MyPhotos"))
            {
                isoFile.CreateDirectory("MyPhotos");
            }

            string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine("/" + "MyPhotos" + "/", imageFileName);
            using (var stream = isoFile.CreateFile(filePath))
            {
                image.SaveJpeg(stream, image.PixelWidth, image.PixelHeight, 0, 80);
            }

            return new Uri(filePath, UriKind.Relative).ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }


    private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        postImage(App.AccessToken,titleBox.Text + descriptionBox.Text, imageSource);
    }

    private void postImage(string p1, string p2, string imagepath)
    {
        FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(p1);
        var imageStream = File.OpenRead(imagepath);
        dynamic res = fb.PostTaskAsync("/me/photos", new
        {
            message = p2,
            file = new FacebookMediaStream
            {
                ContentType = "image/jpg",
                FileName = Path.GetFileName(imagepath)
            }.SetValue(imageStream)
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't pass a forward slashes (**/**) to `Path.Combine`. `Path.Combine` adds slahes for you.

```cs
string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine("MyPhotos", imageFileName);
```

This will make the correct the correct path: MyPhotos/imageFileName where your original code makes the wrong path: /imageFileName

**Edit:**

In `postImage()` method use IsolatedStorageFile's OpenFile method instead of File.OpenRead.

```cs
var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
var imageStream = isf.OpenFile(imagepath, FileMode.Open);
```

Comment: What are you passing to postImage() in the imagepath argument?

Comment: the path of the image returned by the line `return new Uri(filePath, UriKind.Relative).ToString`

Comment: thanks... it works... but is there anyway to check the photo is uploaded or not???

Comment: Aren't you uploading to your facebook account? Check your facebook's photos

Comment: PostTaskAsync() might have some status variable to let you know whether the upload was successful or not. Consult the Facebook C# SDK